# Is there a concise way to find where on an axis the net electrostatic force will be zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge

Given 2 charged points with charges $q_1$ and $q_2$, where $q_1$ is at the origin and $q_2$ is $d_2$ to the right of $q_1$, I am supposed to find an algebraic expression for where a third charge $q_3$ experiences a net force of $0$, along the x axis.  The only way I can think to do this, since I don't have any numbers, would be to use Coulomb's law to get $\frac{kq_1 q_3(\frac{x-d_1}{|x-d_1|})}{(x-d_1)^2}+\frac{kq_2 q_3(\frac{x-d_2}{|x-d_2|})}{(x-d_2)^2}=0$ and then split that into 4 equations due to the absolute values, which would each in turn result in 2 huge symbolic expressions with radicals and what not.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something here that would make the problem more approachable.

Comment: There are only three regions. You haven’t used $d_1=0$. There are no radicals in any region. The expressions are not huge. There is nothing more complicated than some quadratic equations. As the Nike slogan says, “Just do it.”

Answer (score -1):

Since you are working in 1 dimension, consider your equation in a piecewise fashion. You should be able to split your coordinate line into 3 pieces, and intuitive reasoning will reveal the relevant piece that your answer must lie in. Also, the values $q_{3}$ as well as $k$ can be factored out and therefore won't matter, so you won't really need to consider those in your solution. You should find a quadratic equation in $x$ which you know how to solve.